# How to update multiple MongoDB subdocuments in one shot?

Tags: mongodb

I have created a couple of documents in MongoDB:

```
> db.myCollection.insert( {"BUCKET": [{"Field1":"X"},{"Field2":{"A":"B","C":"D","E":"F"}}]} )

> db.myCollection.insert( {"BUCKET": [{"Field1":"Y"},{"Field2":{"G":"H","I":"J","K":"L"}}]} )

> db.myCollection.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("534102c492970f1b06b1edc8"), "BUCKET" : [    {   "Field1" : "X" },   {   "Field2" : {    "A" : "B",  "C" : "D",  "E" : "F" } } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5341054e92970f1b06b1edc9"), "BUCKET" : [    {   "Field1" : "T" },   {   "Field2" : {    "G" : "H",  "I" : "J",  "K" : "L" } } ] }
```

Now I wold like to update it such that all values of "BUCKET" are set to []

So I try this:

```
db.myCollection.update({},{"BUCKET":[]}, false, false)
```

This partially worked. But it only changed the first bucket to []:

```
> db.myCollection.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("534102c492970f1b06b1edc8"), "BUCKET" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5341054e92970f1b06b1edc9"), "BUCKET" : [    {   "Field1" : "T" },   {   "Field2" : {    "G" : "H",  "I" : "J",  "K" : "L" } } ] }
```

So I tried to change the "multi" field to true and tried it again. But it didn't work:

```
> db.myCollection.update({},{"BUCKET":[]}, false, true)
multi update only works with $ operators
```

How can I update multiple subdocuments using the update() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator for your update query to work.  Try this:

```js
db.myCollection.update({},{$set:{"BUCKET":[]}}, false, true)
```